# accessing navigation controller 'target''s properties in segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a segue between a scene and a navigation controller. The navigation controller embeds a view which has a textfield which I want to initialize in the `prepareForSegue` method.

So it's:

Scene A -> Nav controller -> scene B

But, in Scene `A.prepareForSegue`, only Nav controller's properties are allocated, and all Scene B's properties are still nil. So if I do:

```
UINavigationController *cont=[segue destinationViewController];
AddToDoItemViewController *atodo=(AddToDoItemViewController*)cont.topViewController;
[atodo preparetextfield2];
```

It won't work, because the textfield in the todo is still set to nil. So how do I fix this?

And here is the preparetextfield2 method:

```
-(void)preparetextfield2
{
    self.textField.text=@"test";
}
```

Comment: What's in `preparetextfield2`?

Comment: is *cont before that not nil ?

Comment: -(void)preparetextfield2
{
    self.textField.text=@"test";
}

Answer (score 1):

In your AddToDoItemViewController.h file create property to keep the value, for example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
```

And update your text field in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //...Your code
    self.textField.text = self.myString;
}
```

And in preparetextfield2 just update the string:

```
-(void)preparetextfield2 { 
    self.myString = @"test";
}
```

This happened because your controls hasn't been loaded in that stage when you call prepareForSegue so your text field is nil.

Comment: Oke that works. But where can I find this kind of information? With like a timeline of everything that happens when a segue is.. triggered? (is that how you call it?)

Comment: Have a look on UIViewController lifecycle. Google it or check apple doc.

Comment: I guess that's a typo: `(nonatomic,strOng)`? ;)